# Naive Bayes theorem to find probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, naivebayes

I am studying a machine learning course and there is an issue that I can not do. The point is to use this P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A)/P(B) rule to calculate the propability below:

[udacity problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZqOh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First my ML for speech recognition / translation systems is a bit rusty, so I'm probably wrong.
I think what is confusing you it's that it asks for the [bigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram) probability: P(you|if) = P(if, you) / P(if), a formula you can derive from bayes:

- P(you|if) = P(if|you) * P(you) / P(if)

  - P(if|you) * P(you) = P(if, you)
- P(if, you) = 1/22 (21 bigrams + last bigram of OK + STOP)
- P(if) = 1/22 (Assuming no stemming and without simbols)

So: P(you|if) = 1/22 / 1/22 = 1

If you consider stemming things change since "your" will become "you", and I'm also not sure about the end sign 'STOP'.